# Uploading a lambda code along with keras libraries on AWS

Tags: zip, keras, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have a working lambda code, but I have this new idea of a neural network system that I am trying to implement for which I would require Keras (Python). I tried uploading the same working code along with the keras dependencies as a ZIP file form my desktop with an additional "import keras" statement. Funnily , the same code with the additional "import keras" gives me an error saying remote endpoint could not be reached on the developer portal but when I remove the "import keras" statement, my code works perfectly fine. Why is this happening even after I give both the keras dependencies and my lambda code on the ZIP file? I understand that I am not using keras anywhere in my existing code but when I give the keras dependencies and just try to import, logically, it should still work right?

Comment: Without the your code and detailed error messages, It's hard to help your case.

Comment: But the code is working fine without the import keras statement so technically there isn't any problem with the code yeah?